# I'm positive that vs I strongly believe that

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In general, which one is conveys a stronger conviction/opinion? I did some quick google search but didn't find any interesting results.

> I'm positive that

or

> I strongly believe that

Comment: You only said it! *"....stronger conviction.", which means the sentence with *strong* is stronger!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I'm positive" is typically used for **factual** questions and means there is no doubt whatsoever. "Are you sure that you have enough money to pay for a sandwich?" "Yes, I'm positive, I have two thousand dollars in my pocket!" or "No, I'm pretty sure, but I'm not positive, let me count."

By contrast, "I believe" is more typically used for **opinions**. "I believe" expresses an opinion and "I strongly believe" simply makes the opinion more strong (just like it says).

You can also use "believe" for a fact. If you use "believe" for a fact, rather than an opinion, then it's inherently weaker than being positive. You can say for instance, "I believe that I am older than you, but I'm not very confident in that belief." Again putting "strongly" here increases certainty. However, "positive" means that you are 100% certain.

The word "positive" can also be used to mean "optimistic," but typically means that one is optimistic in disposition, not about a particular opinion or fact.

Comment: numerically: for a true/false question, "believe" means your guess is greater than 50%, "strongly believe" is maybe between 75 and 99, "positive" is 100.

Comment: I disagree that it's *always* 100% sure. *Tomorrow is my interview with the US embassy; twice I have got declined. I'm very much afraid this time as well.* *"Ah, don't worry, you'll crack that this time. **Be positive.** He was then 'positive' about it and again lost it. You can be *several times* positive and **retry** it. But I *strongly believed* in that girl and she hurt me. It direct connects to my *belief* and *confidence* in this. We can advise someone *being positive* but I cannot ask someone to *strongly believe* something. And, OP is concerned about which one is *stronger*.

Comment: It is true that positive can mean "optimistic". However, if someone says "I'm positive that [statement of fact]" he means he is 100% sure. If later, he says "I meant that I was optimistic, not that I was 100% sure," the people whom he quoted the fact to would rightfully be upset!

Answer (score 0):

> When you are **positive about something**, you are optimistic. You are *pretty hopeful or expect that to happen.* 
>   When you **strongly believe it**, it's more of your *stance/confidence with affirmation.*

If things don't happen the way you thought.

> In case where you were *being positive* will simply accept it as it was just your hope and expectation. There are still chances that next time, you may still give it a shot and **again be positive.**

Whereas

> In case where you *strongly believed*, you'll lose confidence or faith in that belief. There are less chances that you again believe the same story and go for it in the future.

Comment: Actually you are talking about a different meaning of "positive". It can mean "hopeful or optimistic" but also "completely certain" (and other things). http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/positive

Comment: I am positive this is a different meaning of _positive_ than the meaning asked about in the O.P.'s question. The O.P. is asking about [this meaning](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/positive_1) of _positive_ (certain beyond doubt), as opposed to [this one](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/positive_2) (optimistic).

Answer (score 0):

Stating that you strongly believe acknowledges that it's your belief, as all knowledge is ultimately.

Both express much certainty but 'positive' allows for no doubt while 'I believe' hints at the idea being questionable by acknowledging it to be an belief held.